# Loading Static Files at Runtime with Create React App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, mdxjs

I have a simple Create React App that loads a bunch of static markdown content at runtime and applies an `mdx-loader` to that content to replace any react components found in the markdown.

```js
export default function Page() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const fileName = useFileName(pathname);

  const Content = React.lazy(() => 
    import(`!babel-loader!mdx-loader!../staticMarkdown/${fileName}`)
  );

  return (
      <Suspense fallback={<h1>loading</h1>}>
        <Content />
      </Suspense>
  );
}
```

The `fileName` for the markdown content is dynamic, and it is obtained through the React Router. There are about 25 markdown files that are dynamically loaded by name. They are all in the same folder. I want these files to make it to production. Is there a way to add these files to the static bundle, or load them from the `public` folder? I am not sure what the best approach is for working with React and MDX.